# empty page (root div) when using streamlit

Tags: streamlit

I want to run a streamlit application and for starting I run "streamlit hello"

on the console it shows:
[image]

my .streamlit/config.toml is:

```
[server]
enableCORS = false
enableXsrfProtection = false
```

and when I call it by curl the root div is empty:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no"/>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.png"/>
      <title>Streamlit</title>
      <script src="./vendor/viz/viz-1.8.0.min.js" type="javascript/worker"></script><script src="./vendor/bokeh/bokeh-2.4.1.min.js"></script><script src="./vendor/bokeh/bokeh-widgets-2.4.1.min.js"></script><script src="./vendor/bokeh/bokeh-tables-2.4.1.min.js"></script><script src="./vendor/bokeh/bokeh-api-2.4.1.min.js"></script><script src="./vendor/bokeh/bokeh-gl-2.4.1.min.js"></script><script src="./vendor/bokeh/bokeh-mathjax-2.4.1.min.js"></script>
      <link href="./static/css/5.71be5c0a.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="./static/css/main.b46f6fce.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>
      <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
      <div id="root"></div>
      <script>!function(e){function t(t){for(var c,n,a=t[0],d=t[1],u=t[2],i=0,s=[];i<a.length;i++)n=a[i],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(f,n)&&f[n]&&s.push(f[n][0]),f[n]=0;for(c in d)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(d,c)&&(e[c]=d[c]);for(l&&l(t);s.length;)s.shift()();return o.push.apply(o,u||[]),r()}function r(){for(var e,t=0;t<o.length;t++){for(var r=o[t],c=!0,n=1;n<r.length;n++){var d=r[n];0!==f[d]&&(c=!1)}c&&(o.splice(t--,1),e=a(a.s=r[0]))}return e}var c={},n={4:0},f={4:0},o=[];function a(t){if(c[t])return c[t].exports;var r=c[t]={i:t,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[t].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,a),r.l=!0,r.exports}a.e=function(e){var t=[];n[e]?t.push(n[e]):0!==n[e]&&{7:1}[e]&&t.push(n[e]=new Promise((function(t,r){for(var c="static/css/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{0:"31d6cfe0",1:"31d6cfe0",2:"31d6cfe0",6:"31d6cfe0",7:"f5138d60",8:"31d6cfe0",9:"31d6cfe0",10:"31d6cfe0",11:"31d6cfe0",12:"31d6cfe0",13:"31d6cfe0",14:"31d6cfe0",15:"31d6cfe0",16:"31d6cfe0",17:"31d6cfe0",18:"31d6cfe0",19:"31d6cfe0",20:"31d6cfe0",21:"31d6cfe0",22:"31d6cfe0",23:"31d6cfe0",24:"31d6cfe0",25:"31d6cfe0",26:"31d6cfe0",27:"31d6cfe0",28:"31d6cfe0",29:"31d6cfe0",30:"31d6cfe0",31:"31d6cfe0",32:"31d6cfe0",33:"31d6cfe0",34:"31d6cfe0",35:"31d6cfe0",36:"31d6cfe0",37:"31d6cfe0",38:"31d6cfe0",39:"31d6cfe0",40:"31d6cfe0",41:"31d6cfe0",42:"31d6cfe0"}[e]+".chunk.css",f=a.p+c,o=document.getElementsByTagName("link"),d=0;d<o.length;d++){var u=(l=o[d]).getAttribute("data-href")||l.getAttribute("href");if("stylesheet"===l.rel&&(u===c||u===f))return t()}var i=document.getElementsByTagName("style");for(d=0;d<i.length;d++){var l;if((u=(l=i[d]).getAttribute("data-href"))===c||u===f)return t()}var s=document.createElement("link");s.rel="stylesheet",s.type="text/css",s.onload=t,s.onerror=function(t){var c=t&&t.target&&t.target.src||f,o=new Error("Loading CSS chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+c+")");o.code="CSS_CHUNK_LOAD_FAILED",o.request=c,delete n[e],s.parentNode.removeChild(s),r(o)},s.href=f,document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s)})).then((function(){n[e]=0})));var r=f[e];if(0!==r)if(r)t.push(r[2]);else{var c=new Promise((function(t,c){r=f[e]=[t,c]}));t.push(r[2]=c);var o,d=document.createElement("script");d.charset="utf-8",d.timeout=120,a.nc&&d.setAttribute("nonce",a.nc),d.src=function(e){return a.p+"static/js/"+({}[e]||e)+"."+{0:"4d7af8be",1:"4b5a71cb",2:"8a8e4219",6:"673cfb07",7:"0f1d8953",8:"36495cde",9:"02c82aab",10:"58851391",11:"bd7dd145",12:"57852bcf",13:"42d52fc0",14:"7182e5ec",15:"353742a2",16:"b6f48f03",17:"0af08cc1",18:"b18472bd",19:"92c926e5",20:"75745840",21:"beab59e4",22:"107c7370",23:"9e3cb6aa",24:"0403f5ad",25:"e234116c",26:"4e8bc8a0",27:"a8f1482c",28:"7f928f5b",29:"907c8145",30:"90e1d1d9",31:"3d20a50e",32:"7f0c341b",33:"bb7d120d",34:"ee597234",35:"a376c150",36:"aeccf149",37:"02beb24d",38:"e18dc576",39:"fee314ac",40:"a9dc6cc4",41:"ea0c3f16",42:"81a04ba6"}[e]+".chunk.js"}(e);var u=new Error;o=function(t){d.onerror=d.onload=null,clearTimeout(i);var r=f[e];if(0!==r){if(r){var c=t&&("load"===t.type?"missing":t.type),n=t&&t.target&&t.target.src;u.message="Loading chunk "+e+" failed.\n("+c+": "+n+")",u.name="ChunkLoadError",u.type=c,u.request=n,r[1](u)}f[e]=void 0}};var i=setTimeout((function(){o({type:"timeout",target:d})}),12e4);d.onerror=d.onload=o,document.head.appendChild(d)}return Promise.all(t)},a.m=e,a.c=c,a.d=function(e,t,r){a.o(e,t)||Object.defineProperty(e,t,{enumerable:!0,get:r})},a.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},a.t=function(e,t){if(1&t&&(e=a(e)),8&t)return e;if(4&t&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var r=Object.create(null);if(a.r(r),Object.defineProperty(r,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&t&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var c in e)a.d(r,c,function(t){return e[t]}.bind(null,c));return r},a.n=function(e){var t=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return a.d(t,"a",t),t},a.o=function(e,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,t)},a.p="./",a.oe=function(e){throw console.error(e),e};var d=this["webpackJsonpstreamlit-browser"]=this["webpackJsonpstreamlit-browser"]||[],u=d.push.bind(d);d.push=t,d=d.slice();for(var i=0;i<d.length;i++)t(d[i]);var l=u;r()}([])</script><script src="./static/js/5.c7ec7886.chunk.js"></script><script src="./static/js/main.3fe58c98.chunk.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

and of course in the browser I get an empty page.

a simple run, what do I miss here?

thank you...

Answer (score 0):

after a lot of struggles I finally found the problem.
I had a redirection on my server, and in the WWW/.htaccess I wrote:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^lms/stream(.*?)$ ws://<HOST>:<PORT>/stream$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^lms/(.*)$ http://<HOST>:<PORT>/ [P]
```

instead of:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^lms/stream(.*?)$ ws://<HOST>:<PORT>/stream$1 [P]
RewriteRule ^lms/(.*)$ http://<HOST>:<PORT>/$1 [P]
```